# from one select list/listbox to another jquery way

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to add from one select list/listbox to another, i'm trying like that butit isn't working.

```
$('#Select1').dblclick(function(){
$('<option name="$("#Select1").
            val()">$("#Select1").
            val()</option>').
                             appendTo('#Select2');
});
```

I want on dblclick on one if the items in the listbox = Select1 to be addet to Select2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked up and example that does what you're looking for.

[Add to select box on double click](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanmarc/Vhkj7/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#select1 option:selected').appendTo('#select2');
```

I have made a live page at jsfiddle check if it is ur need

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GSZ8n/)

Comment: Without cloning the selected object before you appendTo it will actually just move it in the dom. $('#select1 option:selected').clone().appendTo('#select2'); I've added a jsfiddle as an answer.

Comment: @ryanmarc yeah i know thats why added add and remove links , i thought he wants model like that thanks for pointing this out

Comment: it's possible that you'd want the option that moved over to the new box to be gone so you can't select it again.  Binding double click events to both of them would allow you to easily move them back and forth.  I added the clone as another option.

Comment: The OP didn't indicate if the item should be removed from the first list or not.  If you are wanting the first item removed, this answer is the better choice.